# Is it possible to play DVDs (or other "optical" media) from file images on Android?

Tags: file-management, media-player, media-files

Is it possible to open DVDs (possibly with all their multimedia features) from a file image on Android ?

(e.g. Nexus Player)

P.S.: Is other optical media handled similar to DVDs from file images, in general?

Comment: why not, have you tried connecting any portable DVD player with OTG to your device?

Comment: It's from file images

Comment: are you looking to extract image file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## VLC can

According to the [documentation](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Android/), [VLC](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.videolan.vlc.betav7neon) can play DVD ISO files and display the relevant menus.

Other players might also be able to play the files if you first unarchive the ISO (using ES File Explorer for instance).

Comment: it is in the description: VLC for Android is a full port of VLC media player to the Android™ platform. It can play any video and audio files, network streams and DVD ISOs, like the classic version of VLC